# How to insert '1001-01-01 00:00:00' into MariaDB when altering a table?

Tags: mariadb, datetime, alter-table, ddl, heidisql

I created a table in HeidiSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `publish_dt` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TS` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Text` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

Then I insert some data into the table, e.g. with

```
INSERT INTO publish_dt (`Text`) VALUES ('Hello')
```

Then I want to change `TS` column to non-`NULL` with a default of '1001-01-01 00:00:00'. I tried to do this in HeidiSQL, it produces the following `ALTER TABLE` query:

```
ALTER TABLE `publish_dt`
    CHANGE COLUMN `TS` `TS` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1001-01-01 00:00:00' AFTER `ID`;
```

However, when I try to save changes in HeidiSQL, I receive the following error from the DB:

```
SQL Error (1265): Data truncated for column 'TS' at row 1
```

Could you, please, clarify why this error happens (I couldn't find the same case with `DATETIME` on the internet) and how to work it around?

Reason for asking: [MariaDB documentation says](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/)

> MariaDB stores values that use the DATETIME data type in a format that
> supports values between 1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000 and 9999-12-31
> 23:59:59.999999.

Comment: The alter is failing because the row has a value of null for the `TS` column. If you remove the 'NOT NULL` from your alter statement it will work correctly though you will still end up with the row you first inserted with a value of null for `TS`. You will get the same error if you do the `alter` without trying to set a default.

Comment: @Dave, I thought the query would replace the `NULL` values with the `DEFAULT`.

Comment: It won't/doesn't. You may change the value of the row before the alter but, as you have it written, the alter will not work as you've seen.

Comment: @Dave, would you like to post an answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alter is failing because the row has a value of null for the TS column. If you remove the 'NOT NULL` from your alter statement it will work correctly though you will still end up with the row you first inserted with a value of null for TS.

You will get the same error if you do the alter without trying to set a default. The `alter` you are trying to use will not replace the null value and, as a result, you are getting the error.

You may change the value of the row before the alter but, as you have it written, the alter will not work as you've seen.